# Vertical mouse scrolling wheel not working in VS 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I tried it with two different mice- both of which work perfectly fine in all other applications. The mouse is MS Intellimouse Optical. I even tried to speed up the vertical scroll through the mouse utility and still nothing.

It barely moves the code a tiny bit and then it stops. I had no problems at all with VS 2008 which is concurrently installed in the same machine.

Am I the only one having this?

Comment: Can you file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)?

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same thing from my IBM ThinkPad.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the IntelliPoint application (ipoint.exe) to run as administrator on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on Windows 7 Machine and it worked for me. Go to Contol Panel -> Mouse -> heel Tab -> Select the radio button "Use Microsoft Office 97 Scrolling Emulation Only" -> Click Ok

I had this issue on my machine and I tried a lot but got nothing. Then I also tried installing VS SP1 also but the problem persisted. Then I tried above method and I am happy that it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the "smooth scrolling" in mouse configuration (control panel). Worked fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I have Lenovo Mouse Suite 6.45

```
1.Control Panel - View by : Large Icon
2.Mouse
3.Lenovo - Adavnce Properties
4.Select Wheel Tab
5.change settings to "Use Microsoft Office 97 Scrolling Emulation Only"
```